# How to set one width for each letter? (word spacing to cover 100% of parent width)

Tags: css

How can I set each letter for same width?
I mean if I have something like that:

```
A B C S A A A A D D D S  
S S C A W I I I I A A A
```

Now lines aren't equal, and letters start from different positions.
I know I can do it using JS, but there is maybe a way to do it using CSS?

Already tried flexbox, but items are aligned in the middle when I need same start and finish position.

Someone know how to set this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

```css
p {
  font-family: Monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>ABCDEFGH</p>
<p>IJKLMNOP</p>
```

Here is a list of available monospaced fonts from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the font, if I take a look at the differences between the editor and the blockquote. I see different results, the biggest difference is the font.

The font used in the Stackoverflow editor is:

```
Consolas
```

If you make a blockquote with the same font used in the editor you will get your result that the letter-spacing is the same no matter which letter you use.

> D A S J X Q
>   K R D V B O

Try to add the above font on the blockquote. This is my result:
[image]

The reason why this happens is because "Consolas" is an monospace font, this means that the width and height are fixed and the same. Because the font in the editor is monospace and the font in the blockquote isn't, the results are different.

You can find more information about monospace fonts in the link below.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font